# python csv write string into 1 cell

Tags: python, facebook, excel, api, csv

I am using the facebook api to get a time, convert it to a different format, and then write it to a csv file. Everything works well except that when the string gets written, it separates the string into 2 different cells like so:

[image]

Help me get it all into 1 cell please. thanks.

my code:

```
import csv
from datetime import *
from time import *
from facepy import *

token = 'CAAErZAZAHDByABA............'
graph = GraphAPI(token)
g = graph.get('apple/posts?limit=4')
mytime = g['data'][0]['created_time']
ctime = datetime(*strptime(mytime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")[0:6]).strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p")


with open('csvtest.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            spamwriter.writerow([ctime])
```

Comment: Could you show your csv file? It looks like problem of importing to OO Calc (or the same software you use).

Comment: As a side note: That `ctime` line is a horrible mess. And it doesn't actually run.

Comment: Also, why do you specify a custom dialect (via `delimiter`, `quotechar`, and `quoting` parameters) in the first place? Is there something in particular you're trying to accomplish with those values, or are you just specifying arbitrary values for fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `quotechar='|'`, but your spreadsheet program isn't understanding that as a quote character.

You can see this pretty easily from the output. Your two cells are not `July 17` and `2013 03:53 PM`; they're `|July 17` and `2013 03:53PM|`.

So, either use a quote character that your spreadsheet knows how to use—the default of `"` should be fine—or change the import settings you use in the spreadsheet to tell it to use your bizarre choice instead of its defaults.

If you used the default `csv` parameters, Excel, Numbers, OO.o, and Libre, and probably any other spreadsheet you can find, would all have no problem with your date field.